# in the Proof that √x is continuous on its domain [0,∞).. where did the √x go ??

Tags: real-analysis

im gonna go straight to the point since everyone here understands this:

$$\left|f\left(x\right)-f\left(a\right)\right|<\:ϵ\:\:\:\:=>\left|\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{a}\right|<\:ϵ\:\:\:\:=>\left|\frac{x-a}{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{a}}\right|\:<\:ϵ\:\:\:\:\:\: \Rightarrow\frac{\left|x-a\right|}{\sqrt{a}}<\:ϵ\:\:\:\left(before\:we\:continue\:where\:did\:\sqrt{x\:}\:go>\:??\right)\:\:\:\:\:\:=>\:\:\:\left|\sqrt{x}\:-\sqrt{a}\right|<ϵ\sqrt{a}\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:$$so $η$ exists $η =ϵ\sqrt{a}$

Comment: Use dollars sentence dollars to display it as MathJax

Comment: It didn't go anywhere.  It was replaced by a different expression.

Comment: i know but how is $\left|\frac{x-a}{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{a}}\right|\:>\frac{\left|x-a\right|}{\sqrt{a}}$

Comment: Actually $\left|\cfrac{x-a}{\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{a}}\right|\leq \cfrac{|x-a|}{\sqrt{a}}$, but the thing is that the arrow (implications) that is needed is the opposite direction $\Leftarrow$.

Comment: It isn't.  That is incorrect.  But we aren't concerned with what $|f(x) - f(a)| < \epsilon$ implies.  We are concerned with wat $|x-a| < \delta$ implies and what $|f(x) - f(a)| < \epsilon$ *IS IMPLIED BY*.

Comment: so we actualy start with supposing that $η=ϵ\sqrt{a}$

Comment: Well, If an alien told us were to start we could.  But seeing as it's up to us to figure that out ourselves we must work backwards by a series of steps where $A$ is implied *by* $B$ which is implied *by* $C$ and so... $|f(x) - f(a)| < \epsilon \Leftarrow .... \Leftarrow |x-a| < \delta_\epsilon$.

Comment: i know that it goes that way but the i just wrote what i read and it confused me ... anyways  thanks to everyone for helping

Comment: We have that $1/(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{a})\leq 1/\sqrt{a}$ because $\sqrt{a}\leq\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{a}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $|f(x) - f(a) | < \epsilon \implies ....$ we don't care what $|f(x) - f(a)| < \epsilon$ implies.

We care what $|f(x) - f(a)| < \epsilon $ is *implied by*.

$ \left|f\left(x\right)-f\left(a\right)\right|<\:ϵ\:\:\:\:<=\left|\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{a}\right|<\:ϵ\:\:\:\:<=\left|\frac{x-a}{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{a}}\right|\:<\:ϵ\\
\:\:\:\:\:\:<=\frac{\left|x-a\right|}{\sqrt{a}}<\:ϵ\:\:\:\\\:\:\:\:\:\:<=\:\:\:\left|x\:-a\right|<ϵ\sqrt{a}\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:$

so $\delta$ exists $\delta =ϵ\sqrt{a}$

And therefore

$|x - a| <\delta \implies |x-a| < \epsilon*\sqrt{a}\implies |\frac {x-1a}{\sqrt a}| < \epsilon \implies |\frac {x-a}{\sqrt{x} +\sqrt a}| <|\frac {x-a}{\sqrt a}| < \epsilon\implies |\frac {x-a}{\sqrt x + \sqrt a}|< \epsilon \implies |\sqrt x - \sqrt a| < \epsilon$

This is a one direction proof.  And the direct is *TO* $|\sqrt x - \sqrt a| < \epsilon$ *FROM* $|x-a| < \delta$.

Answer (score 1):

Let's back up a bit and do this properly:

Prove $f(x) = \sqrt x$ is continuous at any point $a \in [0,\infty]$

Let $\epsilon$ be given. Take $\delta = \epsilon \sqrt a\ $. If $$|x-a| < \delta$$

Then $$|\sqrt x - \sqrt a| = \frac{|x - a|}{|\sqrt x + \sqrt a|} \leq \frac{|x - a|}{\sqrt a} < \frac {\epsilon \sqrt a}{ \sqrt a} = \epsilon $$

**Edit** If $a = 0$, then put $\delta = \epsilon^2$, so that if $x < \delta$, then $\sqrt x < \sqrt {\epsilon^2} = \epsilon$. Note that I dropped the absolute values, since this only makes sense for positive $x$

Comment: What happens in your proof if $a=0$ ??

Comment: $\sqrt 0$ has only RHS limit, not continuous

Comment: Fixed the issue, in the sense that I showed that the right limit exists